# Best practice for validating query parameters in Spring RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have following in my method definition:

```
@RequestParam Map<String, Object> queryMap
```

I have to validate the values in Map.
Are there any spring provided means or assert is the best practice for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General validation protocol for `@RequestParam`:

`@RequestParam("number") @Min(5) @Max(10) int number`

If you need to validate `Map` values, you may have to write certain custom validations.

Answer (score 0):

There is `JSR-303` standard about validation.

Use `@Valid` annotation.

Example code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/appointments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@Valid AppointmentForm form, BindingResult result) {
    ....
}

static class AppointmentForm {

    @NotNull
    private Date date;
}
```

Comment: In my case, inputs are not in a domain class, but rather query parameters.

Comment: You can pack query parameters as a domain class and use such validation.